# How to specify which OS build I wish to do

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-native

Flutter 3.0 is amazing !!
I can make a **web app**, **android** & **iOS** mobile app, *and* a **native Mac app** (and more) all from the one code base.

But now my problem is :
How do I specify which OS to build-for and run-on ?

When I do `flutter run` or debug>run in VSCode it will build-for, and run-on, my Android device first if it plugged in, or else as a Mac app.  I want to run it as Web.  More generally, I want to specify which OS I want to build and run for.

Both the `flutter run` command line option, and the VSCode setting (preferably without messing about with `launch.json`, or else making that seem easy).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```dart
flutter run -d chrome
```

For running it on chrome

```dart
flutter run -d your_device
```

For mobile device

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the selected device. If you select an Android Device, it will build for Android OS. If you select a browser then it will run the build on your Default Browser and the same goes for other scenarios.